# How show only integer values on axis Y?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

There is a line chart shown on the pic:

[image]

And its code is:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
  var options = {
    title: settings.title,
    curveType: "function",
    legend: { position: "bottom" }
  };

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById("chart_div")
  ).draw(data, options);
}
```

How to show only integer values on axis Y? I have pointed by red what I need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `ticks` option to show only integers

```
vAxis: {
  ticks: [0, 1, 2]
}
```

remove this option to remove the dip below the baseline

```
curveType: "function"
```